# Checking same condition in different tables in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add up inventory movements made before a date grouped by product.  I have to check the date from different tables depending on the document type.

Basically I have 3 type of movements: invoices, nulled invoices and other types of documents. The information of those documents are in 3 tables:

- **INVOICES:** `DOC`, `DATE`, ....
- **NULLED_INV:** `DOC`, `DATE`, ....
- **OTHERS:** `DOC`, `DATE`, ....

Then I have all the movements in another table:

- **MOVEMENTS**(`PRODUCT_ID`, `DOC`, `DOC_TYPE`, `QUANTITY`...)

So I need to check the dates in the corresponding table depending on `DOC_TYPE` in order to add up the `QUANTITY` of a movement. For instance if `DOC_TYPE = 1` then check the date of the `DOC` in `INVOICES`, if `DOC_TYPE = 2` then check the date in `NULLED_INV` and if `DOC_TYPE = 3` then check the date in `OTHERS`, and add up all the movements grouped by product:

```
PRODUCT_ID TOTAL_MOVEMENTS_BEFORE_XXXX
1001       10
1002       25
...
```

Any idea in how to make such query?

I tried using an IF in the `WHERE` clause but it didn't work.

Comment: You should create only one `Invoices` table with a new column `DocType`, as you named it or `InvoiceType`, to indicate the invoice type instead of these three tables. Then it will be much more easier to write queries against these two tables.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, the thing is that the table INVOICES has several columns that are not shared by the table OTHERS for example, so if I include all other documents in the same table I would have several empty and also I would have to add columns to INVOICES that will not be used by invoices, just for other type of documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution should be possible with a `UNION`:

```
SELECT product_id, count(*) total_movements_before
FROM movements m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT doc, date
  FROM invoices
  UNION ALL
  SELECT doc, date
  FROM nulled
  UNION ALL
  SELECT doc, date
  FROM others
) sub
ON m.doc = sub.doc
WHERE sub.date < :beforedate
GROUP BY m.product_id
```

I have to add though, why don't you add a column to, say, `invoices` table to indicate the type? That way you could merge you three tables into one and don't require `UNION`s when you want to select from all three (e.g. `SELECT * FROM movements m LEFT JOIN invoices i ON m.doc = i.doc AND m.doc_type = i.doc_type`)

Comment: Thanks Knittl, after minor changes that worked well! Final query:

SELECT m.product_id, sum(m.quantity) as total_mov_before
FROM movements m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT doc, 1 as tdoc, date
  FROM invoices
  UNION ALL
  SELECT doc, 2 as tdoc, date
  FROM nulled
  UNION ALL
  SELECT doc, 3 as tdoc, date
  FROM others
) sub
ON m.doc = sub.doc and m.doc_type = sub.tdoc
WHERE sub.date < :beforedate
GROUP BY m.product_id